# iOS App Won't use custom iCloud container

Tags: ios, xcode, containers, icloud, cloudkit

So, I'm developing two apps that I want to use the same iCloud container.

I have followed all steps as shown in Xcode and apple's online documentation. I added activated the iCloud functionality to my app, checked the CloudKit checkbox, selected a custom container I wanted to work with (obviously the same for both apps).

The app has changed the iCloud container identifier in the entitlements file, which should indicate everything works fine. However, whenever I use the app and print the name of my container, it shows the name of the default container for each app.

for both apps, the Capabilities screen looks like this: 
[image]

I have created one object, `CloudKitController`, to manage all cloud traffic. I intialize it overtime the app launches, and set up variables like this:

```
var container:      CKContainer
var publicDB:       CKDatabase
let privateDB:      CKDatabase
var delegate:       CloudKitControllerDelegate?

override init() {
        container = CKContainer.default()
        print(container.containerIdentifier)
        //this prints the name of the default container for the project
        publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
        privateDB = container.privateCloudDatabase
    }
```

I even went to the developer portal and made sure the container I want to use is the only container both apps are associated with. didn't work either.

My question is: **How can I get two apps, obviously from the same developer account and provisioning profile, to work on one iCloud container?**

Comment: [Edit] your question with relevant code showing how you access the `CKContainer` in both apps.

Comment: Done! would you need any other information? I'd would me more that happy to provide it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You stated that you wish to work with a specific container with a specific identifier. But the code you have is specifically accessing the app's default container. That's not the one you want.

Change:

```
container = CKContainer.default()
```

to:

```
container = CKContainer(identifier: "your shared container id")
```

For further details, read the documentation for the `CKContainer` class.

Comment: I presumed that selecting a container in the capabilities screen of the app would automatically turn that container into the default one. Thanks!

Comment: An app can use the default container, and any number of specific containers, all at the same time. So it would be bad if the default one magically referenced some other specific container.